# error: package "name" does not exist | compiling java project on ubuntu command line

Tags: java

I have completed a java project using IntelliJ IDEA and am currently in the process of taking that project and getting to to run on Ubuntu command line.

**Project Structure:**

```
src/
├─ ADT/
├─ FileIO/
│  ├─ FileObject.java
├─ main.java
├─ javafx-sdk-17.0.0.1/
├─ JavaFXSmartGraph-0.9.4/
├─ InteractiveMode/
```

Snippet start of **FileObject.java**

```
package FileIO;


import ADT.*;

public class FileObject
{
// class code
}
```

Snippet start of **main.java**

```
import FileIO.*;
import ADT.*;
import InteractiveMode.*;
import java.util.*;

public class main
{
// class code that contains main
}
```

I have have included just one java file in FileIO as an example but I do have multiple java files in each of the folders.

I have javafx and javafx smart graph as library which I use in my project.

**What I have tried**
In the src directory I am trying to compile all java files and also include the library's:

```
javac -cp javafx-sdk-17.0.0.1/lib/.jar:JavaFXSmartGraph-0.9.4/.jar *.java
```

Snippet of the errors produced:

```
main.java:12: error: package FileIO does not exist
import FileIO.*;
^
main.java:13: error: package ADT does not exist
import ADT.*;
^
main.java:14: error: package InteractiveMode does not exist
import InteractiveMode.*;
^
main.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
        FileObject fileObject = new FileObject();
        ^
  symbol:   class FileObject
  location: class main
...
```

Please let me know if you require any more information about the project

Comment: Do you use IntelliJ IDEA to compile your application or do you use the command line program `javac`? You are using the `-cp` option, but it does not contain the `.` directory, which might be relevant for loading/finding the `FileIO.FileObject` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by compling with the following:

```
javac -cp . --module-path "javafx-sdk-17.0.0.1/lib/" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml *.java
```